# What desktop environment does startx run, and how can I change it?

Tags: x11, profile, startx, xinit

From many docs, I read that `startx` is starting LXDE in Raspbian OS. I am a little bit confused.

Will always `startx` run LXDE GUI?

Also I have seen example with using `startlxde` command. How is that command different and why `startx` and `startlxde` are running the same GUI(LXDE)? Or maybe it runs it because it is the default GUI?

How can I choose default GUI if I have multiple ones?

Could you please explain more details around the GUI in Linux systems?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`startx` runs `xinit` which starts an X server and a client session. The client session is `~/.xinitrc` if present, and otherwise `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` (the location may vary between distributions). What this script does varies between distributions. On Debian (including derivatives such as Raspbian), `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` runs `/etc/X11/Xsession` which in turn runs scripts in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d`. The Debian scripts look for a user session in other files (`~/.xsession`, `~/.xsessionrc`, `~/.Xsession`) and, if no user setting is applicable, runs `x-session-manager` (falling back to `x-window-manager` if no [session manager] is installed, falling back to `x-terminal-emulator` in the unlikely case that no window manager is installed).

If you want control over what gets executed, you can create one of the user files, either `~/.xsession` or `~/.xinitrc`. The file `~/.xsession` is also used if you log in on a [display manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager_(program_type)) (i.e. if you type your password in a GUI window). The file `~/.xinitrc` is specific to `xinit` and `startx`. Using `~/.xsession` goes through `/etc/X11/Xsession` so it sets up things like input methods, resources, password agents, etc. If you use `.xinitrc`, you'll have to do all of these manually. Once again, I'm describing Debian here, other Unix variants might set things up differently. The use of `~/.xinitrc` to specify what gets executed when you run `startx` or `xinit` is universal.

Whether you use `~/.xinitrc` or `~/.xsession`, this file (usually a shell script, but it doesn't have to be if you really want to use something else) must prepare whatever needs to be prepared (e.g. keyboard settings, resources, applets that aren't started by the window manager, etc.), and then at the end run the program that manages the session. When the script ends, the session terminates. Typically, you would use `exec` at the end of the script, to replace the script by the session manager or window manager.

Your system presumably has `/usr/bin/startlxde` as the system-wide default session manager. On Debian and derivatives, you can check the available session managers with

```
update-alternatives --list x-session-manager
```

or get a more verbose description indicating which one is current with

```
update-alternatives --display x-session-manager
```

If LXDE wasn't the system-wide default and you wanted to make it the default for your account, you could use the following `~/.xsession` file:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec startlxde
```

On some Unix variants, that would only run for graphical logins, not for `startx`, so you'd also need to create an identical `~/.xinitrc`. (Or not identical: in `~/.xsession`, you might want to do other things, because that's the first file that's executed in a graphical session; for example you might put `. ~/.profile` near the top, to set some environment variables.)

If you want to try out other environments as a one-off, you can specify a different program to run on the command line of `startx` itself. The `startx` program has a quirk: you need to use the full path to the program.

```
startx /usr/bin/startkde
```

The `startx` command also lets you specify arguments to pass to the server. For example, if you want to run multiple GUI sessions at the same time, you can pass a different display number each time. Pass server arguments after `--` on the command line of `startx`.

```
startx /usr/bin/startkde -- :1
```

Comment: I am on Debian 9. My machine boots to tty1. From my login running `startx` starts the default Xfce4 session. From my wife's user login on tty1 or tty2. Her `startx` command is set to run Cinnamon (specified in `~/.xsession`). For the second X server I do not have to specify the `$DISPLAY` as noted in the last part of your answer. Although that certainly does work. It automatically makes it the second `$DISPLAY` etc. The setup is great though. There is no logging in and out of a graphical session, just a keyboard shortcut to switch user profiles. Thanks for this helpful answer!

Answer (score 10):

No: `startx` is configurable.  According to the [manual page](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/startx.1.html):

> To determine the client to run, `startx` first looks for a file called `.xinitrc` in the user's home directory. If that is not found, it uses the file `xinitrc` in the `xinit` library directory.

`startx` is not the only way to start X (as you see from `startlxde`).  The `startx` manual page helps again:

> The startx script is a front end to [xinit(1)](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xinit.1.html) that provides a somewhat nicer user interface for running a single session of the X Window System. It is often run with no arguments.

On the other hand, if you want to choose a GUI (LXDE, KDE, etc), then [`xdm`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xdm.1.html) and look-alikes such as `kdm`, `gdm` or [`LightDM`](https://wiki.debian.org/LXDE) are used for selecting different desktop types.  On Debian I generally use `kdm`, because that allows different desktop types.  The packagers for `gdm` disallow most of the desktop types, making it unsuitable for my needs.

`xdm` uses a *different* set of scripts to start, e.g., your `~/.xsession` script along with system scripts.  The look-alikes may ignore this, and use their own scripts.  But it is a starting point.

Comment: So, somwhere in the conf files it is written to run LXDE for example?

Comment: `.xinitrc` is a script, which makes it configurable.  It could run LXDE directly if coded to do this.

Comment: `startlxde` isn't a frontend to xinit, it's a launcher for the LXDE session manager. It isn't a replacement for `startx`, it's something you can execute in `~/.xinitrc`.

Comment: Then it needs some documentation.  Seriously, a *good* answer points the OP in the direction of documentation rather than attempting to rephrase it (unless one has some commentary to make upon the documentation, to make better sense of it).